# Blurry JavaFX 10 TextArea

Tags: java, javafx

I am having problems with a JavaFX Application compiled and run in Java 10. Text inside a JavaFX TextArea appears blurry. Text inside a TextField appears fine (see attached image to compare the two).

I've seen some posts on Stack Overflow and other sites with various suggestions, but none of them work. Some failed solutions included setting -fx-stroke-width, and not wrapping the TextArea in other Panes like AnchorPanes. For me, -fx-stroke-width did nothing; also, the TextArea is not wrapped. Fonts and styles are default for both the TextArea and TextField. Why is the TextArea text noticeably less sharp? I suspect something weird may be happening with Java 10's automatic DPI scaling -- I'm on a HiDPI laptop and the problem does not appear if I disable Windows DPI scaling (though that causes the application to appear far too small, of course).

[image: A picture of a TextArea and TextField; the TextField appears normal, the TextArea text is aliased.]

Relevant code (as per request):

```
GridPane gp = new GridPane(); //GridPane gp is the root of the primary Stage's scene
textArea = new TextArea();
GridPane.setHalignment(textArea, HPos.CENTER);
gp.add(textArea,0,1) //There's a Pane in position 0,0
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant code ?

Comment: @c0der Added to the bottom of the post.

Comment: With DPI scaling the result will be blurry unless the scale factor is an integer.  Scaling up by, say, 125% will give you blurry text.  There is no solution.

Comment: @Jim And how does this explain that a TextField looks ok and a TextArea does not?

Comment: @JimGarrison Not only does the TextField look okay, but even arbitrary text drawn on a Canvas looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blurred text in JavaFX textArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23728517/blurred-text-in-javafx-textarea)